# UMLGraph - How to generate class diagram for a Java project?

Tags: java, uml

Using UMLGraph we can generate class diagram for a java file.
For .eg)

```
java -classpath '/usr/share/lib/UmlGraph.jar:/opt/Java-1.6/lib/tools.jar' \
org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraph -package Test.java
```

Is there any way to generate class diagram for entire complex java project or single jar file using UMLGraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you can generate diagrams for a single class or a single package with all classes in there: http://www.umlgraph.org/doc/cd-umldoc.html

Maybe it is a solution for you to flatten the whole project (copy all files to a single folder) and generate a diagram for this 'package'?

Btw: For a "complex" project it is most likely not very helpful to have a single Class Diagram.

Answer (score 1):

A single class diagram for an entire project is not recommended. I think that creating views is more appropriate.

I like to use my class diagram live navigation to drill down into the project and even multiple projects from packages to classifiers and methods. I can create hundred of live views. No need to save all of them just erase, move, delete etc... directly in the diagram or drag the class form the package explorer or even from the model. Really cool UML when using live views.

It remember me the Hyperion Olap cube in which I could extract business information except that with UML I extract objects :-)